# How to integrate react-credit-cards with redux-form wizards form

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, credit-card, redux-form

Redux-form Wizard http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/wizard/ works great with standard controls from examples. I was trying to integrate more complex controls, such as react-credit-cards [enter link description here](https://github.com/amarofashion/react-credit-cards) and have problems passing its state values into the Wizard redux states onSubmit.

The wizard form is very useful in compiling a list of form data together and OnSubmit sends back the full list of captured form data stored in redux. This type of forms are useful for making registrations, payment informations and surveys etc.

Current behavior?

The use case is to use Wizard sample, and in one of the wizard page bundle with credit card information. The Credit card control is wrapper in the same manner as in renderField class provided int the redux-form examples.

The render class calls the credit card control and create 4 input controls to pass the values of the credit card numbers into the control to draw the creditcard, while copying the data into component state. This is all based on the demo code provided by the react-credit-cards team.

```
  render() {
    const { name, number, expiry, cvc, focused } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="creditCardContainer">
        <h1>React Credit Cards</h1>
        <div className="creditCardForm">
          <CreditCards
            number={number}
            name={name}
            expiry={expiry}
            cvc={cvc}
            focused={focused}
            callback={this.handleCallback}
          />
          <form>
            <div>
              <input
                type="tel"
                name="number"
                placeholder="Card Number"
                onKeyUp={this.handleInputChange}
                onFocus={this.handleInputFocus}
              />
              <div>E.g.: 49..., 51..., 36..., 37...</div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                onKeyUp={this.handleInputChange}
                onFocus={this.handleInputFocus}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <input
                type="tel"
                name="expiry"
                placeholder="Valid Thru"
                onKeyUp={this.handleInputChange}
                onFocus={this.handleInputFocus}
              />
              <input
                type="tel"
                name="cvc"
                placeholder="CVC"
                onKeyUp={this.handleInputChange}
                onFocus={this.handleInputFocus}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

What is the expected behavior?

Need some suggestions as to how to copy the values from the renderCreditCard component states into the Wizard form redux state.

Currently in the Wizard form's onSubmit

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2> {COMPANY} - Sign up form</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
        </p>
        **<WizardForm onSubmit={showResults} />**
        <div className="App-footer">
          <div>Icons made by <a href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="http://www.flaticon.com" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

the redux data return in the callback function does not contain data from the renderCreditCard component injected into Field.

```
const showResults = values => {

  // append primary key to data
  values["id"] = _.uniqueId();
  values["number"] <- this is currently undefined
  values["names"] <- this is currently undefined
  values["expiry"] <- this is currently undefined
  values["cvc"] <- this is currently undefined
  ...
  });
```

when it all works, ideally, the values in the callback shall return number, names, expiry and cvc from Wizard form.

I have tried a couple of methods, including converting renderCreditCard.js input control into Field with component="renderField" without success.

Have anyone tried to integrate react-credit-cards into redux-form? especially in Wizard form pattern? what are some of the ways to propagate the credit card component states back into redux-form?

The issue is track in redux-form [issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3264)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for can be broken down into three questions

1. How do I connect the inputs for credit card information to `redux-form`?
2. How can I access the credit card information stored by `redux-form`?
3. How do I provide that data to the component provided by `react-credit-cards`?

Let's tackle these piece by piece:

---

### Connecting inputs for credit card information to `redux-form`

This step is easy, just use the `redux-form` provided `Field` component.

```
// naturally this is within a component that is wrapped with `reduxForm`
render (
  <form>
    <div>
      <Field
        component="input"
        name="number"
        normalize={ this.ensureCcNumberFormatting }
        placeholder="Card number"
        type="tel"
        onFocus={ this.handleInputFocus }
      />
    </div>

    <div>
      <Field
        component="input"
        name="name"
        normalize={ this.ensureCcNameFormatting }
        placeholder="Name"
        type="text"
        onFocus={ this.handleInputFocus }
      />
    </div>

    <div>
      <Field
        component="input"
        name="expiry"
        normalize={ this.ensureCcExpiryFormatting }
        placeholder="Valid Thru"
        type="tel"
        onFocus={ this.handleInputFocus }
      />
    </div>

    <div>
      <Field
        component="input"
        name="cvc"
        normalize={ this.ensureCcCvcFormatting }
        placeholder="CVC"
        type="tel"
        onFocus={ this.handleInputFocus }
      />
    </div>
  </form>
)
```

Now the fields `number`, `name`, `expiry` and `cvc`, and the associated user input, should be stored in the redux store under the redux form. reducer. Please note that the functions passed to the `normalize` props serve the same function as the bindings to [the `payment` library](https://github.com/jessepollak/payment) in the `react-credit-cards` example: they should take the user input and format the credit cards numbers and enforce length limits. More info about `normalize` [here](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/ValueLifecycle.md/) and [here](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/normalizing/).

Also note that the `onBlur` props should be passed a similar function that is being passed in the `react-credit-cards` example. `redux-form` does not inject a prop to the decorated component that provides information on which input field is selected, so you need to maintain this data yourself (See [this issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1777)).

---

### Accessing data from `redux-form`

Just like anything stored in a redux store I would recommend using [`react-redux` and the `connect` decorator](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) to inject values from your store into components. Happily, `redux-form` also provides [a nifty `formValueSelector`](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/) to use for this purpose.

```
const selector = formValueSelector('MyFormName')

// returns `{ number: '<data>', name: '<data>', expiry: <data>, cvc: '<data>' }`
const mapStateToProps = state => selector(state, 'number', 'name', 'expiry', 'cvc')
```

Now you component should have the credit card information available as props.

---

### Injecting necessary data into the component from `react-credit-cards`

It's easy, just pull the necessary variables from component `props` or `state` and inject them into the `CreditCards` component.

```
render() {
  const { number, name, expiry, cvc } = this.props
  const { focused } = this.state

  return (
    <form>
      <CreditCards
        number={number}
        name={name}
        expiry={expiry}
        cvc={cvc}
        focused={focused}
        callback={this.handleCallback}
      />
      { /* the fields from the first code example down here */ }
    </form>
  )
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I attempt to add your solution and run into some problems with props. Since the credit card states needs to be selected using the selector at the Wizard form level (parent), and then pass back down to CreditCard component. React report problems where props are undefined when CreditCard is rendered.  I have committed the code * [here](https://github.com/kktam/react-reg-wiz-form/commit/60dacbdebf1b7e15532215ab96050a249a36a607) *.  and the error is ```Warning: Failed prop type: React class: prop type `number` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from React.PropTypes.
   in Unknown
...```

Comment: the comment section is too short. I place more details and stack trace in [https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3264](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3264)